# Can I run two instances of Memgraph and use data persistence at the same time?

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I've found the question that explains that it is possible to run [two Memgraph instances at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485144/running-two-docker-instances-of-memgraph-at-the-same-time) when you are using Docker.

I've used the commands from that answer to run the instances:

- Fist instance: `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform`
- Second instance: `docker run -it -p 7688:7687 -p 7445:7444 -p 3001:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform`

This works OK.

I've modified this commands so that I would have data persistence. First instance runs ok, second one is not brought up; `mgconsole` is not shown. I don't see any errors.

- Fist instance: `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform`
- Second instance: `docker run -it -p 7688:7687 -p 7445:7444 -p 3001:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform`

What causes this?

Comment: They probably need different storage as well; does it help to change the volume name (before the colon) in one of the `-v` options?

Comment: @david Maze you are right. I need to use different -v options. I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running two Docker instances at the same time besides different port numbers it is important to use different volumes for data persistance. The correct commands would be:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 3000:3000 -p 7444:7444 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform

docker run -it -p 7688:7687 -p 3001:3000 -p 7445:7444 -v mg_lib2:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform
```